# Code Analysis tool

Tags: c#, dispose, sqlconnection

I am using Visual Studio's code analysis tool, and one of the warnings it gives me is "Do not dispose objects multiple times: Object 'conn' can be  disposed more than once in method 'CycleMessages.discernScan_Reprint()'. To avoid generating a System.OjectDisposedEx you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object. Line:61

```
    private void discernScan_Reprint()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my constring");
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_myproc", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using(cmd)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", param));
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    conn.Close();  // this is line 61
                }
            }

            switch(dt.Rows.Count)
            {
                default:
                    throw new Exception("message");
                case 1:
                    //do Stuff
                case 0:
                    //do stuff
                    break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {throw;}
    }
```

I don't dispose the conn (explicitly via conn.Dispose();), I just close it and allow the using encapsulation to dipose of the conn object- I know I can allow it to be closed via the disposal, but why is it saying I'm disposing it twice? If anything it should warn me saying "You don't need to terminate connections on objects that will be disposed" or something like that. Am I missing something?

Edits:
From ref link on close...

> The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled.

and

> If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent. If the connection pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, the underlying connection is returned back to the connection pool. On the other hand, if Pooling is set to false or no, the underlying connection to the server is closed.

I know that functionally Close() is the same as dispose, but that is not literal from my understanding. When I close the object it is not disposed. It is either closed or returned to the connection pool, disposing (again from my understanding) internally calls the close() methods- so while redundant, I still am baffled as to why it is explicitly saying it is already disposed, when it's not.

Comment: As a side remark, I think you should better close your connection into a `finally` statement to be sure it will indeed be closed.

Comment: I'm surprised the tool didn't also point out that completely unnecessary try/catch.

Comment: @Bartdude that is bad advice, and completely unnecessary; the `using` will do that all by itself; if anything: simply remove the `.Close()`

Comment: The Using statement disposes the object at the end, which calls this.Close() in your SqlConnection. Check that out for more info on the using statement (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @MarcGravell > My bad ! I had overlooked that the `using` statement will indeed be doing that...

Comment: @David That's because in I removed my exception handle for simplicity of post (same with the //do stuff in the case statements).

Comment: @Bartdude Yes, if I plan to reuse the connection then I don't dispose it, and then as a finally I do if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close(); When I do not plan to reuse it I dispose it :)

Comment: @alykins - "I don't dispose the conn, I just close it" - you do. `using(conn) { conn.Close() }` causes a conn.Close(), **and** conn.Dispose() - the end of a using block causes `conn.Dispose();` and `conn = null;` to happen.

Comment: @antiduh I meant I do not do this using(conn){ //dostuff; conn.Close(); conn.Dispose(); } I will edit to clarify that statement.

Comment: @alykins - That would be equivalent to *three* disposes. using statements == automatic Dispose() call.

Comment: @alykins - See my edits on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that implementors provide synonyms for `Dispose` that make sense in the context of the object. One such synonym on [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) is [`Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx):

> Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent.

Since you're explicitly calling `Close()`, and the object's `Dispose()` method is being called when the connection's `using` statement ends, you're effectively calling `Dispose()` twice.

The best approach is to just let the `using` block handle it for you, since it guarantees that `Dispose()` is called even when an exception occurs from inside the `using` block. It also sets the variable to null so that it can be GC'd as soon as possible.

---

**Edits to respond to @alykin's questions**

The documentation says that the `Close()` and `Dispose()` methods are functionally equivalent, but @alykin has identified a scenario where they don't actually do the same thing. If I'm reading her comment correctly, it works something like this:

The following works:

```
SqlConnection conn = GetConnSomehow();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 

// ...

conn.Open();

cmd.ExecuteSomething();

cmd.Close();

// ... time passes ...

conn.Open();
```

The following doesn't:

```
SqlConnection conn = GetConnSomehow();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 

using ( conn ) {
    cmd.ExecuteSomething();
}

// ... time passes ...

// This won't compile, according to alykins.
conn.Open();
```

This shows that SqlConnection objects can be reused, at least when they've been only `Close()`'d.

Likely the reason why the second example with the using block doesn't compile is that the compiler knows that `conn` has been set to null when the `using` block ends, so it knows that you can't call methods on a null object reference.

I'm still not sure that this shows that a `Dispose()` is actually any different than a `Close()` though, since the incongruity arises due to the nulling semantic of the using block. It would be worthwhile testing whether or not an SqlConnection can be re-opened after it is `Dispose()`'d but not nulled. Even if it were, I wouldn't rely on that behavior since it is counter to Microsoft's own guidelines set in the [Dispose Pattern documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Additionally, I would not use the first block that doesn't use a using block - if an exception occurs, the connection may be leaked, or at least, held open for a non-deterministic amount of time until the GC sees that the object has been leaked and invokes its finalizer.

I would not rely on any difference in behavior between `Close()` and `Dispose()` - I would recommend against attempting to re-open a previously-closed SqlConnection object. Let the pooler handle actually keeping the connection alive even if you close or dispose the SqlConnection object you were handed.

---

A note on using statements.

Consider the following block of code:

```
IDisposable thing = GetThing();

using ( thing ) {
   thing.DoWork();
}
```

That block of code is **exactly** identical to this block:

```
IDisposable thing = GetThing();

try {
   thing.DoWork();
}
finally {
   thing.Dispose();
   thing = null;
}
```

And the following block, as considered by Microsoft, their documentation, and their analysis tools, counts as two disposes:

```
SqlConnection conn = GetConn();

using ( conn ) {
    DoWork(conn);
    conn.Close(); // code analysis tools count this as one Dispose().
} // implicit conn.Dispose() from the using block, so that's two.
```

Ignore the fact that Close and Dispose don't *exactly* do the same thing. They don't want you to rely on that, nor should you in case the behavior does actually get fixed.

Comment: What I don't understand is disposing the object disposes it completely whereas closing the object returns it to the connection pool. Which circles me back to my question, if you follow the logic, I close it (returns to connection pool) and then dispose it. I know the easy fix is to remove that line, but I'm trying to understand the meaning behind that message. Do you know why it threw that message?

Comment: @alykins - `Close()` and `Dispose()` both do exactly the same thing, according to the documentation. They'll either both return it to a connection pool, if it is a pooled connection, or they'll both outright close it, if it's not part of a pool.

Comment: No they don't... Try doing this. conn.Open(); cmd.DoSomeStuff(); conn.Close(); //do some stuff; conn.Open(); etc... Now try the same thing but for first statement do using(conn){ conn.Open(); cmd.DoStuff(); } conn.Open(); <- you won't get past this line- it won't even compile. So again while they are similar, they are different. Functionally the same- agree, but that is not the question I am asking. I am asking why is it indicating I am disposing it twice? ugh my tag link is broken for some reason

Comment: Ah I see, so then the documentation isn't exactly correct. The code analysis tool is giving you the error for the same reason I was trying to tell you that they are the same - the code analysis tool thinks that they are the same, so it thinks that if you do them both, then you're disposing twice.

Comment: @alykins - I'm not sure the documentation is exactly incorrect, but maybe misleading. See my edits. I would treat `Dispose()` and `Close()` as being the same, use `using` blocks, and don't bother calling `Close()` manually in your using block; `Dispose()` will do whatever the correct thing is to do. Interesting question and find, btw.

Comment: Yeah, definitely misleading. I know this is probably trivial to most as the remedy is to just remove the .Close(); call- I would like to know the underlying principle though for my own understanding/advancement.

Comment: @alykins - it's just that the code analysis stuff thinks they should be equivalent, and it wants you to remove stuff that isn't necessary; they are fairly strict sometimes. Double-disposing is supposed to be safe, btw, according to the Dispose Pattern docs. I'm not actually sure that double-disposing an SqlConnection is actually safe; you may dispose it once, let time pass, it gets handed to someone else, and your code disposes again while someone else is using it. That's something like a double-free in the C++ world, which leads to brokenness and security vulnerabilities. For now, don't do it

Comment: I don't ever dispose twice as I thought that would throw an error- an underlying reason I looked into this more :/ thanks for info- unless someone posts a more explicit answer I will mark this a little later then and let it die- my curiosity wants me to leave it open (unmarked answer) for a little longer. :P

Comment: @alykins - Remember that `Close()` and then an implicit `Dispose()` from the end of a using block is the same as two dispose calls - according to the docs and the rules of the code analysis tools.

Comment: from your note on using statements- exactly- that is what I would expect it to look like, however what is being indicated is the following: using(thing)
{
  thing.Open();
  thing.DoStuff();
  thing.Close();
}

try
{
  thing.Open();
  thing.DoStuff();
  thing.Close();
  thing.Dispose();
}
finally
{
  thing.Dispose();
  thing = null;
} 
See? extra dispose would be added- I know for a fact- that calling conn.Close(); does not dispose the object- you can close sql connections and reuse them- I'm actively doing it in a different method- I think the horse is dead though lol

Comment: @alykins - and I'm trying to tell you that microsoft wants you to think that Close and any Dispose by any means should be considered equivalent and that they are the same thing. I'm trying to tell you to ignore the fact that they accidentally aren't, because that's probably a bug. .... `using(thing) { thing.Open(); thing.DoStuff(); thing.Close(); }` - thats two disposes. ... `try { thing.Open(); thing.DoStuff(); thing.Close(); thing.Dispose(); } finally { thing.Dispose(); thing = null; }` -- thats three disposes.

Comment: You are missing my point. conn.Close(); does not dispose of the conn object. I will agree that disposing **does** .Close(); but not the other way around. A typical pattern for connections is try{ conn.Open(); //stuff; conn.Close();} catch(sql ex){} finally{ if(conn.State = ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();} <- that pattern would never work if .Close(); did the same as dispose regardless of how it was called (eg Dispose(), using(){}, or contained inside another disposed object (such as cmd in my original post is). I really get what you are saying- but that's not my question- again dead horse

Comment: @alykins - And you are missing my point. Regardless of how things actually work, Microsoft wants you to think, and act as if Close and Dispose are exactly functionally equivalent. And it really is relevant to your original question. The code analysis tools count Close calls as being equivalent to Dispose calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is informing you that the explicit close is disposing resources early. The using statement will automatically dispose it for you.

Answer (score 0):

`close();` and `dispose();` essentially do the same thing, that is why you are receiving this warning. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close.aspx):

> Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent.

Thus, calling `.Close()` disposes of the object.  Additionally, since the object is in a `using` block, the compiler also calls `.Dispose()`.  Only one of the two is needed.  (And the latter is recommended in this case.)

Essentially, you just need to remove the call to `Close()` since the `using` block will handle that for you when it disposes of the object:

```
using (conn)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_myproc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using(cmd)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", param));
        conn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Functionally doesn't mean literally though- as in comment in other answer. When I close it it returns to the connection pool, then I dispose it- I'm really just making more work for myself, but that error shouldn't crop up still as it's not disposed yet. Am I making sense?